# Adding styles to an imported component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following component:

**HelloWorld.js**

```
class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.text}>Hello World!</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

I import it in another file like so:

**SignIn.js**

```
class SignIn extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HelloWorld style={styles.signInText} />
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see in **SignIn.js**, I want to include `styles.signInText` to the component, however this cannot be done as I have already set the style attribute to in **HelloWorld.js**.

I know I could import the styles into **SignIn.js** and have it like so: `<HelloWorld style={[styles.text, styles.signInText]} />` however this is a messy solution.

How can I allow the use of additional styles in my **HelloWorld** component? Thanks.

Comment: you can pass both styles into there then do this.props.styles

Answer (score 2):

If you want the value of the `style` property of `Text` to be a combination of the local `styles` inside `HelloWorld` and the value passed to the `style` property of `HelloWorld`, you could do this.

```
class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={{...styles, ...this.props.style}}>Hello World!</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

This will deconstruct the local `styles` variable into a new object while also deconstructing the `style` property of `HelloWorld`, into the same object.  The final result is passed to the `style` property of `Text`.  Keep in mind though that if the `style` property passed to `HelloWorld` has a property key that also exists in the local `styles` object literal, it will override the one in the local `styles` object literal.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I change style in the `HelloWorld` component to `{{...styles, ...this.props.style}}`, however doing this does not include the styles of `styles.text`. Am I missing something you're saying?

Comment: Based on your code example it should, although I don't see where `styles.text` gets defined in the first place.  Are you sure it's defined by the time you're actually using it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the styles as a prop to the `HelloWorld` component.

**SignIn.js**

```
class SignIn extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HelloWorld signInText={styles.signInText} />
    );
  }
}
```

**HelloWorld.js**

```
class HelloWorld extends Component {
  render() {
    const { signInText } = this.props;
    return (
      <Text style={[styles.text, signInText]}>Hello World!</Text>
    );
  }
}
```